# Dynamic clone and add flex items

Tags: jquery, css

This code works only with 3 elements, when I add another one, its all messed up.

The `js` code:

```
showEditorMenu(["a","b","c"]); // ** adding "d" will mess the order and add 5 elements.

function showEditorMenu(buttons){

  var clone = $(".menuB").clone();
      for(var k=1;k<buttons.length;k++) {
           clone.insertAfter(".menuB").last();
           clone.text(buttons[k]);
       }
...
}
```

the `html+ css:`

```
 <div class="menusC">
    <div class="menuB">A</div>
 </div>

.menusC{
   background-color: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   align-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
 }
 .menusC div{
   height: 22vw;
   width: 22vw;
   margin: 1vh;
   font-size: 5vw;
   outline-width: 0;
   background-color: blue;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: flex; /*FLEX IN A FLEX FOR TEXT*/
   justify-content:center;
   flex-direction:column;

 }
```

So what i expect is to have 3 items in the first row, and another one in the second row.
**When i do this by html and not with code, it works just fine even for 4 elements.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing :

```
  for(var k=1;k<buttons.length;k++) {
       var clone = $(".menuB").last().clone();
       $( ".menusC" ).append( clone );   // ** this !
       clone.text(buttons[k]);
   }
```